# Order of differential form in integral

Tags: calculus, integration

My ap calculus teacher says that when integrating a function with respect to some variable $x$ the $dx$ should go to the right of the function

$\int{f(x)dx}$

I argued that it doesn’t matter where the $dx$ goes since $dx$ is a differential 1-form and so it “commutes” with the $f(x)$ under the integral. In my physics textbooks I often see the $dx$ written in front

$\int{dx f(x)}$

Which is very convenient when dealing with long expressions.

Is my calculus teacher wrong? Do graders tend to “mark off” a point if the $dx$ is in front? I just see it as arbitrary convention

Comment: My high school teacher certainly wanted to mark off, although you'll see both notations on MSE

Comment: The $dx$ at the front is beloved by physicists, but it gets very confusing with multiple integrals.

Comment: @FrankW do you by chance know if graders for the ap calculus bc will care?

Comment: Probably not, but why be so stubborn when essentially the entire mathematics community disagrees with you? (I taught university for 40 years.)

Comment: @Obama2020 My professor said they'd care. I normally write my $\mathrm dx$ in front, but for the exam, I wrote it at the end